# Visualforce mass update

Tags: apex, visualforce, batch

I have a visualforce page which display number of records.user can select multiple records at same time.and on submission some mass update related to this records should happen.

we are thinking of doing it asynchronously.

i understand a visualforce cannot pass input to a batch or anything.

so how do we do this.?is it an asynchronous @future method inside a controller(not in consturtcor/get/set method)

Comment: is the mass update to happen on the records that are on the VF page, or on (a very large number of) other records? In general, if the records fit on a VF page, you will be able to do the update on those records synchronously, which is a better user experience..

Comment: update is to happen on those records and some other records as well.reason why asynchronous option was selected is because--user can select multiple records,and didnt want to hit the limits.client is alright with updates being reflected after sometime..what do you think?

Comment: max # records updated by a synchronous call is 10.000. If you expect to hit that, @future is also not an option because the limit it 10.000 there as well. But 10.000 might do the trick?

Comment: aah okeis.thanks for that..but why do you say synchronous is a better UI experience.what if there a lot of records and wouldnt it take lot of time and user cannot do anything else,if its made synchronous(its for my knowldege)///also to confirm a vf controller cannot pass input to a batch and kickstart it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually a 'normal' update doesn't costs that much time unless the amount of records is really large and/or a lot of triggers etc are fired. You might just want to try it out and see..

If it's not required to give immediate feedback to the user you can indeed make it a lot faster by moving the updates to @future context. You can mark any method in the controller as @future and it will run in asynchronous mode when called.

As for kicking off a batch job from Visualforce; batch jobs always have their own query to determine their scope. So you'd need to flag the selected records in the VisualForce page (and do a dml update!) and then you can kick off the batch job that contains a query to retrieve those records again.

It depends on the business scenario what the best method for you is.

Comment: You can mark any method in the controller as @future and it will run in asynchronous mode when called.-->my understanding was not in constructor/get/set methods.

Comment: that's right but what would be the use case to do it in one of those?

Comment: yes.ie true :)i haven't done any future methods.i am just learning.and saw that in documentation.your inputs have been really helpful..many thanks

Comment: ok, good luck finalizing your code. Pls post again if you run into any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I use the native app [Smart-Tables](http://www.zaapit.com/page/smart-tables) and embed their rich tables into my custom pages, they already took care of everything, they also has mass-create, mass-edit, field-search, [mass-update](http://www.zaapit.com/page/smart-mass-update) and more other cool features.